# How to display file size in vim rulerformat?

Tags: statusline, ruler

I want to display file size in the `rulerformat` in `vim`.

Please answer for all file size formats like bits, bytes, kibibytes, mebibytes, gibibytes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the size of the buffer in bytes with:

```
:echo line2byte('$') + len(getline('$'))
```

[`line2byte()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#line2byte%28%29) gets the number of bytes until the last line, but not *including* the last line, so we need to add the length of the last line ourselves.

You can use `%{expr}` to use any expression inside the `statusline` or `rulerfrmat` settings; for example:

```
let &statusline .= "%{line2byte('$') + len(getline('$'))}"
```

Or to display as KiB etc. simply divide by 1024, 1024^2, etc. A handy function might be something like:

```
fun! HumanSize(bytes) abort
    let l:bytes = a:bytes
    let l:sizes = ['B', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB']
    let l:i = 0
    while l:bytes >= 1024
        let l:bytes = l:bytes / 1024.0
        let l:i += 1
    endwhile
    return printf('%.1f%s', l:bytes, l:sizes[l:i])
endfun

let &statusline .= "%{HumanSize(line2byte('$') + len(getline('$')))}"
```

Which will display a size as "Bytes", "KiB", etc. depending on what makes the most sense.

Comment: I have `set rulerformat=%55(%l,%c%V\ \ \ \ %L\ \ \ \ 0x%B\ \ \ \ %p%%%)` in my `vimrc`, now when I copy pasted the `fun!` block in my `vimrc` and edited the ruler format line after it to be `set rulerformat=%55(%l,%c%V\ \ \ \ %{HumanSize(line2byte('$') + len(getline('$')))}\ \ \ \ %L\ \ \ \ 0x%B\ \ \ \ %p%%%)` but it gives error.

Comment: You need to escape the spaces with a backslash @GypsyCosmonaut, after `line2byte()` etc. I recommend you use the `let &rulerformat` syntax as I used in my answer, instead of `set`. That way you won't have to add so many backslashes :-)

Comment: I tried `line2byte('$') + len(getline('$'))` and checked the actual file size. But its value seems to be `file_size - 1` when the file has EOL in the last line, and `file_size + 1` when the file doesn't have EOL in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of the file that is loaded in the current buffer with: `getfsize(expand(@%))`. To add it to the statusline you would use:

```
let &statusline .= "%{getfsize(expand(@%))}"
```

Be aware that it will show -1 for the size of a new unnamed buffer and will update on modified files only after they are saved.